# Why could Mobius M. Mobius not recognise Loki?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

In the end of Loki S1 E6, Mobius M. Mobius was not able to recognise Loki. Why is it so?

Comment: Since this is a Season 1 cliffhanger the answer will be in Season 2. Anything else is opinion based speculation,

Comment: It's a different TVA.

Comment: @Paulie_D And it is! Apparently it was the past of the TVA, not truly alternate version.

Answer (score 7):

This is because, depending on who you ask, either Loki was sent to a different timeline of the TVA or reality was rewritten after Sylvie kills He Who Remains.

> It’s a good plan that quickly goes sideways. No sooner does he reach Mobius and Hunter B-15, “He realizes that in the time he's been sitting on that step, something has changed.”
>
> “Something has changed reality, including the reality of the TVA,” Hiddleston says. “The three statues of the Time Keepers are no more. In their place is a statue of Kang. And that his friend Mobius doesn't recognize him and doesn't know who he is. His destabilization in that moment is profound.”
>
> <sub>[Marvel, ‘Loki’: How the Cliffhanger Ending Sets the Stage for What’s Next](https://www.marvel.com/articles/tv-shows/loki-cliffhanger-tva-he-who-remains-kang)</sub>

> Farahani reveals that the look and design of the Kang statue was a game day decision designed by the in-house VisDev team. He assures Marvel.com that the entire set dressing of the TVA architecture was identical to the TVA we started the series with, in order “to delay the audience and Loki’s understanding that they were in a different place, that they were in a different timeline.”
>
> <sub>[Marvel, Loki: Deconstructing He Who Remains’ Life’s Work at the Citadel at the End of Time](https://www.marvel.com/articles/tv-shows/loki-he-who-remains-citadel-end-of-time-kang-statue)</sub>